# gcc how to add library path correctly?

Tags: gcc

I am on Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit platform. I want to compile a library to fix google earth missing panaramio picture frame.

```
 /* amirpli 2013/11/28 */
 #include <QtCore/QAtomicInt>
 extern "C" {
int _Z34QBasicAtomicInt_fetchAndAddOrderedPVii(QAtomicInt* a, int b) {
    return a->fetchAndAddOrdered(b);
     }
 }
```

I try to compile it with

```
gcc -O3 -fPIC --shared baifaao.cpp -o baifaao.so -IQtCore
```

But I get

```
baifaao.cpp:2:29: fatal error: QtCore/QAtomicInt: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Qt4 installed in my system

What should I do to compile it?

Comment: maybe you need to create a `.pro` file and use `qmake`

Comment: I don't know how to add above parameters to make a qmake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have added the directory `QtCore` to the include path.  That's wrong, you have to add the parent directory to the include path: `-ItheParentDirectoryOfQtCore`, if it's the current directory then just `-I.` is sufficient.

Comment: Many thanks to you man, you saved my day. At first I copied QtCore next to source code then `gcc -O3 -fPIC --shared baifaao.cpp -o baifaao.so -I.`  It worked. I'm grateful.